# Call jquery methods inside knockout viewmodel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I need to change the `tr` `background-color` when mouse is clicked over it. I bind the `click` event using knockout because i need to update my viewmodel when user clicks over each table row.

I'd need to call `$(row).css('background-color', 'red');` inside my viewmodel.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/391/

My view model:

```
function ViewModelTrazas(data) {
var self = this;
self.trazas = ko.observableArray();
array = self.trazas;
self.selectRow = function (row) {
    self.seletedRow(row);
    // HERE I SHOULD CHANGE THE TR BG
    // SOMETHIN LIKE THIS:
    // $(row).css('background-color', 'red');
}
self.seletedRow = ko.observable();
}
```

The html:

```
<div id="gridAndDetail">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="margin-top:-4px;
                                height: 200px; overflow:auto;">
                <table id="datagrid" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead style="text-align:left">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Machine</th>
                            <th>Event type</th>
                            <th>Detail</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: trazas">
                        <tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectRow">
                            <td data-bind=" text: Fecha"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: Maquina"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: TipoEvento"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: Mensaje"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(using jquery `click` event binder should do the job but I don't know why I'm not able to select all my `tr` using this selector:

`$('#datagrid tr').click(function(){});`

It only matches the `thead` section of the table.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Knockout trying to solve things with jQuery should not be your first choose.

The more KO way if doing this is to define a css class like red and toggle that css class with the [`css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) depending on the selection:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And in your viewmodel:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectRow, 
               css: {red:  $parent.seletedRow() == $data}">
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q3Uuz/)

An alternative approach would be to a have an `isSelected` property on your individual items. Then you can set `isSelected` property in your `selectRow` handler and use this new `isSelected` in your css binding instead of the parents `$parent.seletedRow() == $data` expression.